# LED strip Windows computer controlled

Tags: led, programming

I've bought a bunch a LED strips
[image]

A friend has built a system using http://resolume.com/ with http://www.heroicrobotics.com/products/pixelpusher controllers, however from what I've read this is geared toward iOS.

> An easy-to-use iOS application is available from [LED Labs](http://ledlabs.co/) - specifically designed for PixelPusher, and supporting it seamlessly.

I am a Windows programmer by trade and want to program these LED strips using C# ideally.

I just want to know how I can output to the LED strips via a Windows PC? I'm fine with the software side I just need some guidance with outputting to the hardware.

<sub>*Programmatically using a 1 dimensional array of RGB co-ords I can sequence, eg a few functions with `for loops` to create shows.*</sub>

Help much appreciated!

Comment: do you have LED drivers already? if not, how do you plan to drive the LEDs? i can think of arduino boards and a custom driver board.

Comment: @Umar I only have these 10 LED strips that come with IR remotes. I have investigated Raspberry Pi (as demonstrated in AWS) and Arduino's just not sure how to hook the strips up and out put to them via Visual Studio, lots of examples using Python just not C#

Comment: Finding an SDK is a shopping question. Finding an alternate controller is also a shopping question. Writing an SDK is a software question (and a very broad one at that). Help me out here -- in what way is this at all on-topic for this site?

Comment: Hi @DaveTweed, I understand and have edited the question to *hopefully* be within the boundary of this site's rules. I dont want to delete as I feel Husrev's answer and my question will help people in the future. I hope you dont close it, cheers.

Comment: The bad thing about this question is that the second link EXPLICITLY SAYS IT SUPPORTS WINDOWS MACS AND LINUX.

Comment: @Passerby feel free to close, it says Java, not C# and using the `UDPClient class` was the answer I was looking for. I didn't really want to use IKVM...

Comment: There's no reason to close this question... I was simply addressing the part where it seems like you think it's IOS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use Visual Studio with C# to implement this. The board you've mentioned has an ethernet interface, so it is completely controllable via UDP. Sending and receiving packets are unbelieveably straightforward in C#. The device must provide its interface to control leds driven by the ARM, just check and set the bits of the packet content.

There are many examples such as [UdpClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

What you need to know is the info that what bytes in the UDP content change the LEDs, the company should be clear on this.

Comment: OK, cool, I have programmed RS485 (DMX512) in the past, seems like I need to back myself and purchase a few of these PixelPushers, you couldn't add a link or something with an example how to implement it? Ie Send UDP packets?

Comment: "The software side of things is handled by an open, routable UDP protocol..."  I just've checked the website and couldn't find the documentation regarding to this. Maybe they ship a CD with the board? You should make sure of it first. Contact the company and ask for availability of such a documentation.

Comment: If it's via Ethernet, presumably it'll be via localhost on a port, then just `Response.Write`s or something like that.

Comment: OK, yes I will contact the manufacturer, thank you, I think this answers my question, if not I can ask another one when I have more info. Thanks again, will mark this as correct tomorrow night.

Comment: Yes, there are many examples such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx What you need to know is the info that what bytes in the UDP content change the LEDs, the company should be clear on this.